# How do i set a timer for a textView ? This keeps crashing my app

Tags: java, android, thread-sleep

How do i set a timer for  `TextView` ? This code keeps crashing my app

```
 final TextView textwel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcometext);
 Thread timer = new Thread() {
     public void run() {
         try {
             // this should sleep for 4 seconds
             sleep(4000);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         textwel.setText("Welcome");
     }
 };
```

start the timer

```
timer.start();
```

Comment: Thats a bad approach man. Cuz it will also produce a nullpointer exception when the View is destroyed while your background thread calls the View late already.

Comment: Use a Handler for this.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work.

Since the new thread that you create is not the UI thread, you can't update the UI (setting the text of a text view) on that thread.

A better way to do this would be to use the `android.os.Handler` class. It has a `postDelayed` method that will execute a `Runnable` with a delay. [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) is the docs.

Alternatively, you can use this `Timer` class I wrote, which encapsulates a `Handler` instance and has a simple interface:

```
import android.os.Handler;

public class Timer {
    private Handler handler;
    private boolean paused;

    private int interval;

    private Runnable task = new Runnable () {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!paused) {
                runnable.run ();
                Timer.this.handler.postDelayed (this, interval);
            }
        }
    };

    private Runnable runnable;

    public int getInterval() {
        return interval;
    }

    public void setInterval(int interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    public void startTimer () {
        paused = false;
        handler.postDelayed (task, interval);
    }

    public void stopTimer () {
        paused = true;
    }

    public Timer (Runnable runnable, int interval, boolean started) {
        handler = new Handler ();
        this.runnable = runnable;
        this.interval = interval;
        if (started)
            startTimer ();
    }
}
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/Sweeper777/85c61eb30d1deccbd664d91b6d4fdcc2)

You would probably use it like this:

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        textwel.setText("Welcome");
    }
};
Timer timer = new Timer(run, 4000, true);
```

P.S. setting the textview's text to "Welcome" every 4 seconds is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You can you use CountDownTimer api to update TextView timer which is very easy to use and convenient.

Here is the simple example:

```
TextView tvTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer((durationInMilis * 60000), 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)));
            tvTime.setText(hms);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish()
        {
            // Do your other task on finish
        }
    }.start();
```

This code this will update tvTime text every second and run for sepecified amount of time in durationInMilis. Output will look like hh:mm:ss e.g 01:23:57

If you don't want show anything on update then leave onTick() callback blank and update your TextView in onFinish(). Just pass value to parameter durationInMilis for which you want to run timer.

If you have any doubt please feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

why are you using textview??

Chronometer is a class provided by android that implements a simple timer so my suggestion is use it in place of textview.

here is the [official link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html)

Answer (score 0):

//use it, its easy and simple

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {

          textwel.setText("Welcome");
       }

   }, 4000);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this , it will work 100%  and also UI will not stuck

```
Thread timer = new Thread() {
     public void run() {
         try {
             // this should sleep for 4 seconds
             sleep(4000);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
// after sleep call a UI thread
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textwel.setText("Welcome");
                        }
                    });
     }
 };
```